# Problemas na hora de criar migrations - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com problemas ,para criar uma migration no terminal exibe isto...

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "make:migrations" is not defined.
  Did you mean one of these?
      make:migration
      make:auth
      make:command
      make:controller
      make:event
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:mail
      make:middleware
      make:model
      make:notification
      make:policy
      make:provider
      make:request
      make:seeder
      make:test`
```

Este é um projeto pronto quero apenas criar as tabelas e fazer o relacionamento ,para depois povoar no banco 
 Até quando eu crio um model usando o comando - `php artisan make:model Teste` 
 ele cria o model a migration não.

Exemplo de um model meu : que não tem migration, e que gostaria de ter no banco

```
     <?php

     namespace App\Models;
      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 


    class Projetos extends Model{ 

    public $timestamps = false;    
    protected $table = 'projetos';

    protected $IntId = 'id';
    protected $fillable = array('nome', 'area', 'data_criacao', 'data_conclusao_prevista', 
                                 'status', 'porcentagem', 'codigo', 'dono', 'descricao');
    protected $strDataUltimaAtualizacao = 'data_ultima_atualizacao';
    protected $strArquivo = 'arquivo';
    protected $strDescricao = 'descricao';
    protected $strDataArquivoAtualizacao = 'data_arquivo_atualizacao';

    public function areas() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Area', 'id', 'area');
    }

    public function stakeholders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Stakeholders', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
    }

    public function comentario() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comentario', 'id_projeto', 'id');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
    }

}
```

Outra questão ,levantada existe este model , pra eu criar ele no banco é com uma migration,este model ele tem uns relacionamento com outros models..

Exemplo model Stakeholders:

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'stakeholders';
protected $IntId = 'id';
protected $fillable = array('login', 'nome', 'email');
protected $boolAdmin = 'admin';
protected $boolBoss = 'boss';
protected $strSenha = 'senha';
protected $strTokenResetarSenha = 'token_resetar_senha';

public function projetos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
}

public function comentario() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comentario', 'id_stakeholder', 'id');
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
}
```

A migration de projetos fiz foi deste jeito ... gostaria de saber se estar certo

```
Schema::create('projetos', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome',200);
        $table->string('area',30);
        $table->date('data_criacao',20);
        $table->date('data_conclusao_prevista',20);
        $table->string('status',40);
        $table->integer('porcentagem',80);
        $table->integer('codigo',10);
        $table->integer('dono',40);
        $table->string('descricao',80);

        //relacao
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();            
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('area');

        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id')->references('id')->on('stakeholders');

        $table->integer('id'->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('comentarios');
```

Fiz me baseando nesta video-aula  [Criação de relações entre tabelas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gc5LByf3nL4)

Se estiver certo , a mesma lógica faço na migration stakeholders.. correto?

Comment: Como você está dando o comando no terminal? Comando completo

Comment: O comando normalmente utilizado para migrations no laravel é: `php artisan migrate --seed`

Comment: Valeu !!!  muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta está na própria pergunta...

```
Command "make:migrations" is not defined.
  Did you mean one of these?
      make:migration
```

**make:migrations** - não é definido, o comando é sem o **s** no final

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

Comment: Tem mais algo que possa ajudar? Se puder aceitar como melhor resposta por ter resolvido seu problema. Acredito que outros usuários também poderão vir a ter a mesma dúvida algum dia.

Comment: Sabe-se que para executar as migration usa este comando ` php artisan migrate`  mas exibe este erro - ` [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '{'` vou editar e mostrar minha migration na pergunta

Comment: Isso, poste a migration que está tentando rodar, esse segundo erro deve ser referente a alguma coisa faltando nele, ponto e virgula, fechamento de bloco, parenteses...edita na pergunta que edito a resposta tbm

Comment: Consegui resolver Darlei... estou com dificuldade pra entender um pouco a questão do relacionamento entre tabelas...

Comment: Pode me chamar no e-mail, face ou skype, posso te ajudar com qualquer duvida... darleizillmer@hotmail.com